# drupal view displaying different output in different pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a panel displaying a drupal view. Its context type is set to Node id. This is the same setting for 2 pages. However, it is displaying different output for the 2 pages. I have to refresh it multiple times to see the same output on both pages. How can this be fixed?

Comment: what is different about the output?

Comment: on 1 page it displays 5 different items, on another page the same view displays 5 different items. But on multiple reloads, both the pages display the same output. I want this view to display the same list on each page.

Answer (score 0):

try using the #drupal or #drupal-support channels in an IRC client.  There's always a  ton of helpful Drupalers there and it would be easier to troubleshoot with someone if you could chat through additional details as needed...

Answer (score 0):

Does the view have a sort? If not try adding one. If that doesn't work I would need to see the behavior and the admin settings to be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am using a view to sort by node comments in descending order. I think the problem is the context (Node id) which i am using.